# Lazy loading page within iFrame is cut off (vertically) on iOS devices only when scrolling

Tags: ios, iframe

I have a kiosk web page that loads a 55px header and an iFrame taking the rest of the window below it. Inside the iFrame I have a page that lazy loads a grid of items. We load 50 items at a time and then load another 50 and so on. Each item is appended to a container div within the iFrame's content page.

This does not present an issue with desktop browsers or Android devices. However, on iOS devices, it lets me swipe down for some of the page but then is cut off randomly - not allowing me to swipe to the bottom of the content page.

I have read that you should put your iFrame inside a div. I have done that as shown here:

```
<header class="kiosk-header">
   CONTROLS
</header>
<div id="kiosk-bid-app-container-div">
  <iframe id="kiosk-bid-app-container" src="page.php" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.kiosk-header {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #fff;
    height:55px;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}

#kiosk-bid-app-container-div {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 55px);
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
    margin-top:55px;
}

#kiosk-bid-app-container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

I don't have control of the content page (page.php listed in the example).  I'm not sure where to go next. I've read the responsive iOS iFrame pages listed here but that doesn't fix the limited Y scrolling I see in the iOS devices (using browserstack to test).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I changed the top three lines. It happens to be a quirk in mobile safari for it to not obey the width of your iframe.

```
#kiosk-bid-app-container-div {
    width: 1px;
    min-width: 100%;
    *width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 55px);
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
    margin-top:55px;
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I tried the top three lines but my challenge is that the lazy load renders a height that the iFrame won't let me scroll to. The issue isn't related to width at this point unless I'm missing something.